# Why is avy-goto-line so slow?

Tags: performance, avy

If I open a file with, say, 2 lines, then when I call `avy-goto-line` emacs shows me in the beginning of each line the keybinding to move the cursor over there.

But try it in a bit longer file (I use a file with 160 lines). It will take about 0.5-1 seconds in order to process the command.

Why is `avy-goto-line` so slow? Any way to improve it or any alternative to it?

Thank you

IMPORTANT EDIT: I can reproduce this when I have 145 lines on the screen (I use a screen in vertical), with fewer lines the process is faster.

Comment: It works fine for me. You should try to load avy with a minimal configuration and see if it improves. If it doesn't I would post on the avy GitHub page and describe the exact steps to reproduce it.

Comment: @eflanigan00 thank you! How many lines fit your screen?

Comment: It works fine for me as well even on large files

Comment: I can split to 4 windows in one frame and avy provides selections for all lines on all 4 vertical windows